# Cadenas dinámicas a veces no guardan el contenido correspondiente

Tags: array, c

Estoy realizando un codigo más grande en el que implemento algo parecido a esto. El problema que me sucede es que cuando la cadena dinamica copia el contenido correspondiente  del arreglo de cadenas, parece no copiarlo o copiar un espacio en algunas ocasiones. Ya que al mandar a imprimir
generalmente hace lo que espero, pero a veces no imprime nada y no entiendo el por qué. ¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#define MAX 30

int main()
{

int c = 0;
srand(time(NULL));

    do
    {
    int i;
    int mv = rand()%7;

    char *movimiento = (char *) calloc (MAX, sizeof(char));
        if(movimiento == NULL){
            printf("\nEspacio de memoria insuficiente...\n");
        exit (0);
        }

    char mb [7][MAX] = {"Deposito","Retiro","Pago con tarjeta","Pago servicios","Consulta saldo","Aclaraciones", {0}};
        for (i=0; i<mv; i++){
            strcpy(movimiento, mb[i]);
        }
        c++;

        printf("%i:%s\n", c, movimiento);
        fflush(stdout);

        free(movimiento);
        movimiento = NULL;

    } while (c<30);


return 0;

}
```

Comment: No comprendo para qué usas el for. Y el espacio en blanco aparece por el elemento `{0}` que hay en el arreglo.

Comment: Uso el for para llegar al elemento al que debo llegar en el arreglo de cadenas segun el número aleatorio y copiarlo al arreglo dinamico, creo que no se ve con tanto sentido en el código que puse pero esta parte me daba problemas en un programa más grande, con estructuras de datos. Gracias por recordame lo de {0}, creí que en los arreglos de cadenas se utilizaba como también se utiliza en una sola cadena. Muchas gracias Mateo, con eso y la respuesta de abajo pude resolver el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mv` es un numero al azar:

```
int mv = rand()%7;
```

Cuando `mv` vale `0`, nota que en el `for`:

```
for (i=0; i<mv; i++){
    strcpy(movimiento, mb[i]);
}
```

No se copiara nada a movimiento.

Por eso es que algunos salen vacios.

Comment: Muchas gracias, con el comentario que me hicieron y tu respuesta pude resolver mi problema. Me había despistado totalmente de excluir el 0 en el numero aleatorio y no me percate como afectaba esto al ciclo. De verdad muchas gracias, me salvaste jejeje